# Scroll left-to-right on HTML Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible for the user to scroll left and right in this table? Right now, no scrollbar appears and I miss data on the right hand side.

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/6wf0te1d/

**Code:**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="generic__content col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

    <style type="text/css">
      .table tr td:first-child, .table thead tr td {
        font-weight:bold;
      }
      .table tbody tr td {
        border-right:1px solid black;
      }
      .table tbody tr td:last-child {
        border-right:0;
      }
      table tr td:nth-child(2), table tr td {
        text-align:center;
      }
      table img {
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .zui-table {
          border: none;
          border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          border-collapse: separate;
          border-spacing: 0;
          font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .zui-table thead th {
          background-color: #DDEFEF;
          border: none;
          color: #336B6B;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: left;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .zui-table tbody td {
          border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          color: #333;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .zui-wrapper {
          position: relative;
      }
      .zui-scroller {
          margin-left: 141px;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
          width: 100%;
      }
      .zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
          border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: auto;
          width: 140px;
      }
      </style>
 
      <!--<div style="overflow-x:auto;">-->
      <div class="zui-wrapper">
        <div class="zui-scroller">
          <table class="table table-striped zui-table">

            <thead style="background:#FCE6E7">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><img src="coffee.svg">Cup of coffee</td>
                <td><img src="beer.svg">Local beer/lager</td>
                <td><img src="can-of.svg">Can of coca-cola</td>
                <td><img src="glass-wine.svg">Glass of wine</td>
                <td><img src="mineral-water.svg">Still mineral water</td>
                <td><img src="suncream.svg">Sun cream</td>
                <td><img src="insect.svg">Insect repellent</td>
                <td><img src="burger.svg">2 course lunch for 2</td>
                <td><img src="evening-meal.svg">3 course evening meal for 2</td>
                <td><img src="taxi.svg">Taxi ride</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Bulgaria</td>
                <td>&pound;1</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Turkey</td>
                <td>&pound;2</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Portugal</td>
                <td>&pound;3</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Spain</td>
                <td>&pound;4</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Greece</td>
                <td>&pound;5</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Cyprus</td>
                <td>&pound;6</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Croatia</td>
                <td>&pound;7</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Malta</td>
                <td>&pound;8</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">France</td>
                <td>&pound;9</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Italy</td>
                <td>&pound;10</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove width:100% class **.zui-scroller**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="generic__content col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

    <style type="text/css">
      .table tr td:first-child, .table thead tr td {
        font-weight:bold;
      }
      .table tbody tr td {
        border-right:1px solid black;
      }
      .table tbody tr td:last-child {
        border-right:0;
      }
      table tr td:nth-child(2), table tr td {
        text-align:center;
      }
      table img {
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .zui-table {
          border: none;
          border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          border-collapse: separate;
          border-spacing: 0;
          font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .zui-table thead th {
          background-color: #DDEFEF;
          border: none;
          color: #336B6B;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: left;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .zui-table tbody td {
          border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          color: #333;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .zui-wrapper {
          position: relative;
      }
      .zui-scroller {
          margin-left: 141px;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
         
      }
      .zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
          border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: auto;
          width: 140px;
      }
      </style>
 
      <!--<div style="overflow-x:auto;">-->
      <div class="zui-wrapper">
        <div class="zui-scroller">
          <table class="table table-striped zui-table">

            <thead style="background:#FCE6E7">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><img src="coffee.svg">Cup of coffee</td>
                <td><img src="beer.svg">Local beer/lager</td>
                <td><img src="can-of.svg">Can of coca-cola</td>
                <td><img src="glass-wine.svg">Glass of wine</td>
                <td><img src="mineral-water.svg">Still mineral water</td>
                <td><img src="suncream.svg">Sun cream</td>
                <td><img src="insect.svg">Insect repellent</td>
                <td><img src="burger.svg">2 course lunch for 2</td>
                <td><img src="evening-meal.svg">3 course evening meal for 2</td>
                <td><img src="taxi.svg">Taxi ride</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Bulgaria</td>
                <td>&pound;1</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Turkey</td>
                <td>&pound;2</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Portugal</td>
                <td>&pound;3</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Spain</td>
                <td>&pound;4</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Greece</td>
                <td>&pound;5</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Cyprus</td>
                <td>&pound;6</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Croatia</td>
                <td>&pound;7</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Malta</td>
                <td>&pound;8</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">France</td>
                <td>&pound;9</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="zui-sticky-col">Italy</td>
                <td>&pound;10</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
                <td>&pound;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
table {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to you code:

```
.zui-wrapper {
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Remove from your code:

```
.zui-scroller {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
.zui-scroller {
      margin-left: 141px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: visible;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

change width: 100% to auto

```
.zui-scroller {
      margin-left: 141px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: visible;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      width: auto;
  }
```